# Connection to Oracle Application Express through ElasticSearch JDBC

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, oracle11g, logstash

I want to import data from an Oracle database to a ElasticSearch cluster. To test this, I created a test database with Oracle Application Express but I cannot connect to it.
The workspace is called TEST.

Here is my logstash code:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080/xe"
        jdbc_user => "TEST"
        jdbc_password => "pass"
        statement => "SELECT * from person"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know, you can't *export* data from an Apex workspace, it just doesn't make sense. A Workspace is used as a "container" for your applications, not data. Data is stored in the database itself.

Basically, you install a database and then install Apex on that database. As Apex ADMIN user, you create a workspace, "map" it to a database schema, create developer and then you create an application which manipulates with data stored in the underlying schema.

Therefore, I think you got it wrong - it is a database schema (user) that should be a source in that operation. Forget about Apex, I'd say that it is irrelevant here.